# Blogger Data and Widgets with HTML Template

Tags: html, blogger

I have create a template for blogger in HTML/CSS and added "Add Widget Sections". The template is working 
online.

Now there are two issues:
1- The layout page looks nothing like the layout created. Here is the snapshot of the blogger layout page.
[image]

Generally the layout page of any custom templates available online or available on blogger is 
[image]

2- If Iam adding any widgets, no data is displayed.

How to correct the issues ? I guess there is some programming mistake. I have simply designed the template
and created widget sections. Any tutorials on "How to integrate HTML/CSS template with blogger?
or how to convert html templates to blogger templates?

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue 
This happens when you remove the Default CSS files added by Blogger from your template ,change

```
&lt;style &gt; &lt;!--<b:skin><![CDATA[]]></b:skin>
```

to

```
<b:skin><![CDATA[]]></b:skin>
```

About the second issue , can you please share a URL of the blog ?
The second issue is a bit vague and I am not able to understand whether you are not able to save widget or After saving the widget is not displaying correctly , Please can you explain the issue in more detail